# Mybatis "Creating a new SqlSession" & "Closing non transactional SqlSession" for *every* database query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

Mybatis seems to create and close a `SqlSession` for *every database query* (e.g. if in one http request we do two database queries, then two sessions are created and destroyed). Is this normal (will it lead to poor performance), and how shall I fix it?

Details:

The logs -

```
Creating a new SqlSession
SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@4b7e4174] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@163878081 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@162e1fc3] will not be managed by Spring
Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@4b7e4174]
Creating a new SqlSession
SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@5d9714ab] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@91618474 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@162e1fc3] will not be managed by Spring
Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@5d9714ab]
```

The codes -

```
Article a1 = dao.selectById(123);
Article a2 = dao.selectById(456);
```

where the Dao is a normal Mybatis `Mapper`. (More specifically, it is a [mybatis plus](https://mp.baomidou.com/en/guide/quick-start.html) `BaseMapper`)

Thanks for any ideas!

---

P.S. My naive thoughts -

The [official doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html) says -

> If you're using a web framework of any sort, ...upon receiving an HTTP request, you can open a SqlSession, then upon returning the response, you can close it...

Thus, my situation is abnormal. Since in one http request with two database queries, I see *two* SqlSessions instead of one.